# C#. NPOCO. Error: "Incorrect syntax near '&'. " when trying to join

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, npoco

I have this stored procedure, created by NPOCO after the next linq query:

```
var componentVarians = _repository.Get().Include(x => x.Component)
                .Where(x => x.IsActive == true &
                            x.ServingTypeId == servingType &
                            x.Component.IsActive == true &          
 x.Component.BotanicalName.ToLower().Contains(value.ToLower())).ToList();


exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [CVD].[Id] as [Id], [CVD].[Name] as [Name], [CVD].[Sku] as [Sku], [CVD].[ServingTypeId] as [ServingTypeId], [CVD].[Price] as [Price], [CVD].[IsActive] as [IsActive], [CD].[Id] as [Component__Id], [CD].[BotanicalName] as [Component__BotanicalName], [CD].[HebrewName] as [Component__HebrewName], [CD].[PinYanName] as [Component__PinYanName], [CD].[IsActive] as [Component__IsActive], [CD].[CreatedDate] as [Component__CreatedDate] FROM [ComponentVariant] [CVD]  
  LEFT JOIN [Component] [CD] ON [CVD].[ComponentId] = [CD].[Id] 
WHERE (((([CVD].[IsActive] = @0) & ([CVD].[ServingTypeId] = @1)) & ([CD].[IsActive] = @2)) & upper(lower([CD].[BotanicalName])) like @3 escape ''\'') ',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 nvarchar(4000)',@0=1,@1=1,@2=1,@3=N'%A%'
```

After executing this stored procedure, I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '&'

Comment: In the Linq `Where` expresion put `&&`not only one `&`. In T-SQL how said @LasseVågsætherKarlsen `AND`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your query to be double &&

```
var componentVarians = _repository.Get().Include(x => x.Component)
    .Where(x => x.IsActive == true &&
                x.ServingTypeId == servingType &&
                x.Component.IsActive == true && 
                x.Component.BotanicalName.ToLower().Contains(value.ToLower())).ToList();
```

Comment: It will work for linq to objects, but as this is linq to sql the conversion cannot be parsed correctly

Comment: I understand. The `&` operator for boolean operands is still a logical operator in C#, I assumed Entity Framework would still use it as such, it makes no sense to translate it to the `&` symbol in the resulting SQL, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the Linq expresion:

```
var componentVarians = _repository.Get().Include(x => x.Component)
    .Where(x => x.IsActive &&
        x.ServingTypeId == servingType &&
        x.Component.IsActive && 
        x.Component.BotanicalName.ToLower().Contains(value.ToLower())).ToList();
```

The properties of type bool do not use `x.IsActive == true` or `x.IsActive == false`.
if you want to filter when it is `false` evaluate with`!x.IsActive`